# AngularJS ScrollTop on Click Directive. How do I stop an inner click from triggering the outer directive click.

Tags: jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive, scrolltop

I built a directive to scroll a section into view after a delay which is to compensate for the section animating open then added functionality to stop the scroll if the user attempts to scroll the screen at all manually.

```
angular.module("scrollOnClick", [])
.directive('scrollOnClick', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, $elm, $window) {
            $elm.on('click', function() {
                var $viewport = $('html, body');

                $viewport.bind("scroll mousedown DOMMouseScroll mousewheel keydown", function(){
                     $viewport.stop()
                });     

        setTimeout(function () {   
            var winH = window.innerHeight
            var oSet = (winH / 2) - 222
            $viewport.animate({scrollTop: $elm.offset().top - oSet}, "easing", function(){
                $viewport.unbind("scroll mousedown DOMMouseScroll mousewheel keydown");
            }); return false;
        }, 201);
      });
   }
  }
});
```

My problem is I have a button inside the section that I don't want it to trigger a scrollTop animation. Any idea's how to stop it?

Comment: try `return false;` when handling click event of the button

Comment: I'm not sure I know exactly what you mean. If you literally mean ng-click="return = false;" That doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
$elm.on('click', function(event) {
   if (event.target == this){ //run code only when the clicked target is the current element.
    //your code

   }
}
```

Another solution is adding this code:

```
$elm.find("button").on('click',function(event){
   return false;//prevent default and stop propagation.
   //or event.stopPropagation();
});

//your code 
$elm.on('click', function() {
```

To use `.find` with selector, you may need to include jQuery

Comment: I have several other divs in the section that I do want to be clickable. It's just the button I don't want to trigger it...

Comment: @user3161466: then just modify your code to check if `event.target` is the button

Comment: @user3161466: I added 1 more solution

Comment: seemed like a wonderful fix maybe I'm implementing it wrong.var $button = $(".cmpButton"); 
                if (event.target != $button){

Comment: @user3161466: The first solution is still better in case you don't want to stop event propagation completely and just need to bypass the event in that `specific case`.

Comment: @user3161466: try `if (event.target != $button[0])`

Comment: I have jquery included. Every one of your answers was good and I have no idea why not one of them worked.

Comment: @user3161466: I really have no idea why. Any errors in the console? And do you have multiple buttons with the same class `cmpButton` ?

Comment: @user3161466: try `var $button = $elm.find(".cmpButton");` to search for the child button of the current element

Comment: I tried that already. I do have several buttons with the same class the section is in ng-repeat. I have tiles that have an image with a rollover and a title when you click it opens a span with more information on the item. Think google images style. each image is the whole section with an image a title and a button for downloading. I want everything but the download but to trigger the scrollTop.

Comment: @user3161466: It's good if you can post the html. Another way to check (assuming only the buttons have `cmpButton` class) is `if (!$(event.target).hasClass("cmpButton"))`

Comment: That last one did it. Thank you so very much.